# segment a query result in mysql according with the number of rows

Tags: mysql

I need a way to show results of ten in ten but I have no idea how? for intance in this table.

```
+---------+----------+--------+
|  place  | address  |  time  |
+---------+----------+--------+
|  place1 | address1 |  3:00  |
|  place2 | address2 |  5:00  |
|    .    |     .    |    .   |
|    .    |     .    |    .   |
|    .    |     .    |    .   |
|    .    |     .    |    .   |
+---------+----------+--------+
```

I know is not suitable a table like this but it's only as example

Comment: Do you want MySQL to return the result "in tens"? Or do you want to show the result "in tens"? I mean, pages with 10 results each.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "in tens". By tens of minutes? Ten results total? Can you add more rows of sample data and your expected results?

Comment: I mean, select registers by alphabetic order but at first show ten results, after the next ten and so on. the reason is because if I have too much items it's not good to show all rows in the same time

Comment: In that case, there are 2 possibilities : use Ajax to show results on the same page 10 by 10, or, refresh the page showing 10 results each time. Is that what you want? Imagine two buttons : "Previous 10" and "Next 10".

Comment: yes, is that I want but I would want to know if there is a way to do that only with mysql query or I need other things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show 10 results you can use a `LIMIT` at the end your select:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
ORDER BY address
LIMIT 10;
```

If you want to show the next 10 after that, you can add the offset by doing `LIMIT offset, count` like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
ORDER BY address
LIMIT 10, 10;
```

The third group would be `LIMIT 20, 10` and so on and so forth. Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37f0aa/1) example.

Note that the pattern here, if you need something dynamic, is that the `nth` group will always have `LIMIT (10 * (n - 1)), 10`.

Comment: @ReneLimon glad I could help! In case you didn't see it, I just edited my answer with an extra comment regarding the pattern here, which may help make it dynamic for your example. If you are displaying 10 results per page, if you know the page number you can query for the proper group using the generic expression I added.

Comment: yes, I'm using a bootstrap pagination and I only send the number of item.every time I nedd it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
$query_count=mysql_query($sql);

$per_page =10;//define how many record for a page
$count = mysql_num_rows($query_count);

$pages = ceil($count/$per_page);

if($_GET['page']==""){
      $page="1";
}else{
      $page=$_GET['page'];
}

$start    = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
$sql     = $sql." LIMIT $start,$per_page";
$query2= mysql_query($sql);
?>

<ul id="pagination">
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++){ ?>
<li id="<?php echo $i;?>"><a href="linktoyourfile?c=<?php echo $c;?>&page=<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></a></li>
<?php  } ?>
</ul>

<table>
  <tr><th>place</th><th>address</th><th>time</th><tr>
   <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
       echo "<tr><td>".$row['place'] ."</td>"."<td>".$row['address'] ."</td>"."<td>".$row['time'] ."</td></tr>";
} ?>
</table>
```

Use above code for pagination